# How to debug static fields of a running c# application outside VS debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, static-members

Is there a way to access static members of a c# exe assembly at runtime outside VS debugger?

Comment: If you mean within the VS debugger, sure. Just set a breakpoint and add the static field to the Watch list. If you mean outside of the debugger, well that's very difficult. You'd be better off attaching the VS debugger to an already running instance.

Comment: @p.s.w.g can you give steps to watch variables in attach mode?

Comment: Just to be clear, please confirm if you are using Visual Studio or a different IDE (and what version you're using).

Comment: @p.s.w.g I'm using VS Express 2012 and I don't have the source code

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily add a breakpoint, in a debugger, most of them support this "feature", and you will be able to see the values inside static fields. If you are using Visual Studio, you can even add a watch or type the name of static value in Immediate Window, and you willl also be able to see the value of the static field.
Other methods cosist in logging to print the values at runtime.

Comment: But I don't have the source code, only a protected exe

Comment: Well, if you don't have the source code, then you can't access it, you can try disassembly, but it won't give you much information?